# assign value to char pointer, but say Access violation writing location

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

```
void main() {
    char *x;
    x="abc";
    *x='1';
}
```

Why it comes with error "Access violation writing location"?

I cannot assign value to `x` by `*x='1'`?

Answer (score 3):

Modifying string literals leads to undefined behavior, try using `char` arrays instead:

```
int main() {
    char x[] = "abc";
    *x ='1';
}
```

Also note you should use `int main()`.

Or if you prefer to use pointers, use this a little redundant example:

```
int main() {
    char x[] = "abc";
    char *y = x;
    *y ='1';
}
```

Comment: void strcpy(char *s, char *t)  {       
    while((*s = *t) != '\0') {
        s++;
        t++;
    }
}

Comment: @user2756494 I assume you mean this function violates the rule? That's not true, the first parameter passed to `strcpy` should never be a string literal. The rule isn't against modifying `char` pointers, it's against modifying string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Thats wrong because you are attempting to modify a string literal. It is created in readonly mode and if you will try to change that then it would be an access violation and hence result in error.

As a solution as to how it can be achieved you can try using `char` arrays

Answer (score 0):

The application is loaded in several memory regions (memory pages), code read-only executable (program counter can run in it), and string literals might ideally go into a read-only region.

Writing to it would give an access violation. In fact is nice that you get that violation, are you running Windows? That would possitively surprise me.