# char pointer, Access violation writing location

Tags: pointers, char

```
void cpy(char *s, char *t)  {         
while((*s = *t) != '\0') {
    s++;
    t++;
  }
}
void main() {
char *x;
char *y;
x="abc";
y="zzz";
cpy(x,y);

}
```

what it wrong with this function? is the part *s=*t wrong? always says "Access violation writing location"...

Comment: You asked a similar question few minutes back:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670912/assign-value-to-char-pointer-but-say-access-violation-writing-location

Comment: It's about don't modify string literals, as I answered in the other question of yours:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18670947/1009479

Comment: Dont modify the string literal as they are read only!!!

Answer (score 0):

The strings that you specify in quotas is constant strings and stores in read only memory. So after

```
x = "abc"
```

x points to read only memory area. And when you try to write there with cpy you get the exception.

Comment: is that means we means we cannot change any single char of the string by pointer?

Comment: If pointer points to read only data you cannot. You can make r/w copy with strdup("abc"). And don't forget about free it after use.